# Is CLT and AB test valid , when the test have repeat visitors making repeat pruchases

Tags: hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem, ab-test

The Central limit theorem states that variables in population of the mean should be independent. But, when doing an AB test in a website, we have large numbers of visitors that will be coming back to website during the test duration and making repeat purchases as well.

In this case, is the CLT and AB test hypothesis testing using T test still valid, because the visitors are no longer independent.

Here is the AB test scenario. Say I have an app to make purchases - say hotels in site like a hotel booking platform.  ~30% of the customers have top tier status (makes 5+ purchases in 1-2 month period).  and even remaining ~40% come back often ( 2+ in a month). I am running an AB test for say 45 days ( to get minimum sample size) and wanted to measure conversion rate and revenue/shopper as the metrics for the AB test to check if they are significant across control and test.

Since the visitors are not independent (and hence conversion rate and revenue/shopper are not independent) and there are many significant portion of them(and since CLT needs the population random variables to be independent), can I use the normal hypothesis testing mechanism for statistical significant and confidence intervals

Thanks you for any responses.

Comment: Depends on the structure of the test.  If you are analyzing average spend per group, you could for instance sum each customer's spend and then take the mean.  That is one way to ensure each observation is independent.

Comment: @DemetriPananos is there a way to get this for conversion rate ? Also, to measure 'revenue/shopper', do you propose to take the "sum (revenue)/visits" at the visitor level. instead of doing revenue per visit at visit level?

Comment: Conversion is a binary variable, no?  Either a customer converts in their visit or they do not.  If you need help with an AB test, please post the details of the experiment.

Comment: true, conversion is binary. But the same customer comes back to the site multiple times - say 20-30 times over a 45 days period and he books multiple reservations. And majority of customer will fall under this category. Sure, will update.

Comment: In general, when we use conversion rate as metric in AB test, then the assumption is that the binary variables are all independent(each customer can book or not randomly and one customer is not related to other - but here most of them are related).

Comment: What are customers convertiing on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107020/discussion-between-tjt-and-demetri-pananos).